# Using .groupby() and determining if columns are showing duplicated grouped values or varyinig values

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, pandas-groupby

I am looking to group by column ['W'], and then determine if the groupings in the columns exhibit variance.  I have tried a few iterations of `.groupby()` followed by `.duplicated()`, but can't seem to get the code right for what I intend.

For the df below:

```
import pandas

df

W X Y Z
A 2 3 4
B 2 1 1
A 1 3 4
B 2 1 4
C 2 1 1
```

Grouping by ['W'] would result in the following:

```
df

W X Y Z
A 2 3 4
A 1 3 4

B 2 1 4
B 2 1 1

C 2 1 1
```

You see above that when grouped by ['W'] variance occurs in column ['X'] in grouping A, but not in grouping B nor C.  For columns ['Y'] and ['Z'], no variance occurs in any groupings.

If grouping by ['W'] causes a variance to occur in at least one grouping for columns ['X'],['Y'], or ['Z'], that whole column should be outputted in df2 as "Varying."  Otherwise, that column will be listed as "Duplicated."

```
X         Y           Z
Varying   Duplicated  Varying
```

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

---

EDIT: As Zero pointed out, I have corrected the df's so they are identical.  Also, to clarify, I am looking to see if columns X, Y or Z vary after grouping by W.  For this, I hope to have a single output for the whole column.  If at least 1 grouping varies in that whole column, then the whole column is listed as "Varying."  Thanks!!

EDIT 2: Z Should be varying.

Comment: Hey Zero, I corrected to address your comments. Thanks for catching my varying dfs! that was not intended. To clarify, if ONE grouping varies, then the whole column is listed as "Varying"

Comment: Thanks Zero.  That is correct. Z should vary due to B.  My output was using an archaic example I initially had in my comment.  Thanks again for your due diligence.  This is probably the last time I post a question at 3AM because it is rife with errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1]** Using `np.std`

```
In [280]: (df.groupby('W').agg(np.std)
             .fillna(0).eq(0).all()
             .replace({False: 'Varying', True: 'Duplicated'}))
Out[280]:
X       Varying
Y    Duplicated
Z       Varying
dtype: object
```

**Option 2]** Using `nunique`

```
In [272]: (df.groupby('W').agg(lambda x: x.nunique() != len(x) or len(x) == 1)
             .all()
             .replace({False: 'Varying', True: 'Duplicated'}))
Out[272]:
X       Varying
Y    Duplicated
Z       Varying
dtype: object
```

**Option 3]** Using `duplicated`

```
In [273]: (df.groupby('W').agg(lambda x: x.duplicated(keep=False).any() or len(x) == 1)
             .all()
             .replace({False: 'Varying', True: 'Duplicated'}))
Out[273]:
X       Varying
Y    Duplicated
Z       Varying
dtype: object
```

---

Details

```
In [275]: df
Out[275]:
   W  X  Y  Z
0  A  2  3  4
1  B  2  1  1
2  A  1  3  4
3  B  2  1  4
4  C  2  1  1
```

For o1

```
In [281]: df.groupby('W').agg(np.std).fillna(0)
Out[281]:
          X    Y        Z
W
A  0.707107  0.0  0.00000
B  0.000000  0.0  2.12132
C  0.000000  0.0  0.00000

In [282]: df.groupby('W').agg(np.std).fillna(0).eq(0)
Out[282]:
       X     Y      Z
W
A  False  True   True
B   True  True  False
C   True  True   True
```

And o2

```
In [273]: df.groupby('W').agg(lambda x: x.nunique() != len(x) or len(x) == 1)
Out[273]:
       X     Y      Z
W
A  False  True   True
B   True  True  False
C   True  True   True

In [274]: df.groupby('W').agg(lambda x: x.nunique() != len(x) or len(x) == 1).all()
Out[274]:
X    False
Y     True
Z    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
f = lambda x: 'Duplicated' if x == 1 else 'Varying'
df.set_index('W').groupby('W').nunique().applymap(f)

            X           Y           Z
W                                    
A     Varying  Duplicated     Varying
B     Varying  Duplicated     Varying
C  Duplicated  Duplicated  Duplicated
```

Comment: piRSquared, Thanks for helping out with this.  I clarified slightly in my edits.  Is there a way to adapt this so that we obtain one output for each column if at least one grouping is varying?  Also, My two df's were differing on accident in my example, which I corrected for.  Thanks for helping!!